# gazebo 1.9.1 : openni_kinect plugin does NOT refresh cabinet(-like) objects when move manually

Tags: gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a world where I move cabinet or similar objects (they have wood texture) and the gazebo_ros_openni_kinect driver doesn't refresh the data. It keeps seeing them even if they're no longer there in gazebo, when I point with the sensor to their old location.

This doesn't happen if I use the regular cube object.

You can see a video showing this issue here: http://youtu.be/wuyAfVP8Ohk

I'm using *gazebo 1.9.1* and *ros-hydro*.

I haven't try, but I guess this also happens with the gazebo_ros_depth_camera plugin.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6914/gazebo-1.9.1-:-openni_kinect-plugin-does-not-refresh-cabinet(-like)-objects-when-move-manually/) by [Enrique](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/466/enrique/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Solved!

The problem was that the objects (cabinets, bookshelves, tables) where static in the world: 1

Changing that to 0 has solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Enrique](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/466/enrique/) with karma: 16 on 2014-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0